# how to edit the setcookie code for samesite=lax

Tags: samesite

I tried several changes but i could not get the solution.
How to edit this setcookie code for samesite=lax /or strict

```
<a href="" onClick="cookienumberone('COOKIEXYZ','0','-1')">
<button type="button">buttontext</button></a>

<script>
    function cookienumberone(){
       days=30; // number of days to keep the cookie
       myDate = new Date();
       myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
       document.cookie = 'COOKIEXYZ=0; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: solution for above: document.cookie = 'COOKIEXYZ=0; SameSite=Lax; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();

and the cookie for the login, the same question:

```
setcookie("cookie_login",$rs->row["login"],time()+60*60*24*365,"/",str_replace("http://","",surl));
```

Comment: It's not clear what language / framework your `setcookie()` call is for, but I would expect one of the parameters to be the `SameSite` attribute value. If it does not support `SameSite`, then some frameworks let you specify an arbitrary string at the end that will be appended. Alternatively, you may need to set the `Set-Cookie` header manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For client-side JavaScript, you specify `document.cookie` in the same format as the `Set-Cookie` header.

e.g.

```js
document.cookie = 'same-site-cookie=foo; SameSite=Lax';
document.cookie = 'cross-site-cookie=bar; SameSite=None; Secure';
```

For you framework, which appears to be PHP, as of PHP 7.3.0 the
[`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) method
supports the `SameSite` attribute in its options and will accept `None` as a
valid value.

```php
setcookie('same-site-cookie', 'foo', ['samesite' => 'Lax']);
setcookie('cross-site-cookie', 'bar', ['samesite' => 'None', 'secure' => true]);
```

For earlier versions of PHP, you can also set the
[`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) directly:

```php
header('Set-Cookie: same-site-cookie=foo; SameSite=Lax');
header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=bar; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

Comment: this is working fine: 
document.cookie = 'COOKIEXYZ=0; SameSite=Lax; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
now have to find a solution for the last one too: 
setcookie("cookie_login ...

Comment: What language / framework / library is your `setcookie()` call?

Comment: $_SESSION["people_id"]=$rs->row[ "id_parent" ];
    $_SESSION["people_name"]=$rs->row[ "name" ];
    $_SESSION["people_login"]=$rs->row[ "login" ];
setcookie("cookie_login",$rs->row["login"],time()+60*60*24*365,"/",str_replace("http://","",surl));
    setcookie("cookie_password",$rs->row["password"],time()+60*60*24*365,"/",str_replace("http://","",surl));

Comment: Looks like you're using PHP, so I've added an example there.